# Does ATI or Nvidia support HDMI 3D without proprietary glasses/hardware?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, amd-graphics-card, 3d-vision

So I currently have HDMI going from my computer's ATI card to my TV.  The TV supports 3D via standard 3pin hookup for an emitter+shutter glasses.

It's an older ATI card which doesn't support AMD HD3D, so I have to use 3rd party drivers like iz3d or TriDef for gaming.

I am able to use Bino 3D software to watch 3D movies.

In both cases the card outputs the correct 3D signal, TV displays the 3D content, and the TV controls the shutter glasses.

Various problems with my current setup have gotten me to looking at getting a new TV and possibly new card.

1) I would like to replace my card with a card that has support for ATI/NVidia driver that supports outputting 3D formats.  The 3rd party drivers have various problems as a result of how they have to inject into the games.  I feel like either AMD HD3D or NVidia 3D Vision drivers would work better since they are native(i.e. don't have to be injected)

2) I would like to replace my TV with a newer 3D capable TV(of the problems mine has, one significant one is overscan can't be disabled and GPU scaling looks terrible).

The reason I'm here is I feel like I'd rather have a TV with 3D support and use it's shutter glasses, instead of a 3D Vision kit(since 3D Vision glasses can't be used with the TV independently).  That way I'd be free to change to ATI card later and just continue using the same TV+Glasses, and also be able to watch 3D content from other sources besides my computer.

So I have a couple questions along these lines.

**Can both ATI HD3D and NVidia 3D Vision output standard HDMI 3D frame packing, such that I can just use a 3D TV+TV's Shutter glasses(instead of using the NVidia kit)?** I feel Yes, but just want to make sure.  I saw some post that seemed to imply that you still have to buy the 3D Vision kit and have the emitter plugged in so you have a license for the 3D Vision driver???

**What is the advantage of the using NVideo's kit+glasses instead of the TV's glasses?**  I have heard some say it overcomes the HDMI 1080p@24fps limit, but I think that might be wrong based on the response here that indicates HDMI supports 60fps in 3D: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/331042-28-hdmi-limit

What makes a TV compatible with 3D Vision(using NVIdia kit, instead of )?  I would think since the NVidia glasses are controlled by the card, then TV doesn't have anything special to do.  I would think that any 120hz capable TV would work with 3D Vision?

**How bought for AMD HD3D, will any 120hz 3D TV work that supports standard HDMI 3D frame packing?**  They have a VERY short list of recommended TV's on the HD3D site which makes me think there is something properietary that the TV must have to be compatible?

Comment: Well I screwed up and mispelled stereoscopic.  The tag should NOT be hyphenated, if someone with tag edit privilages wants to fix it.

Comment: Unless a moderator can override it, I can't create a stereoscopic tag when a stereo-scopic tag already exists. I've removed the incorrect tag for now, as the unused tag should drop out sometime...